# How to transform date in Stata?

Tags: date, time-series, stata, finance, line-plot

I've looked for help on the internet for the following, but I could not find a satisfying answer: for an assignment, I need to plot the time series of a certain variable (the term spread in percentages), with years on the x-axis.

However, we use daily data. Does anybody know a convenient way in which this can be done? The 'date' variable that I've got is formulated in the following way: 20111017 represents the 17th of October 2011.

I tried to extract the first 4 numbers of the variable 'date', by using the `substr(date, 1, 4)` command, but the message 'type mismatch' popped up. Also, I'm not quite sure if it gives the right information if I only use the years to plot daily data (over the years). It now gives the following [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awFov.png), which doesn't look that nice.

Comment: This must be one of the most discussed topics in the Stata world, with hundreds of posts on Statalist alone.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the question in your title.

The `date()` function expects a string. If your variable with value `20111017` is in a numeric format you can convert it like this: `tostring datenum , gen(datestr)`.

Then when using the `date()` function you must provide a *mask* that tells Stata what format the date string is in. Below is a reproducible example you can run to see how this works.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input float datenum
20111016
end

* Convert numeric variable to string
tostring datenum , gen(datestr) 

* Convert string to date
gen date = date(datestr, "YMD")

* Display date as date
format date %td
```

If this does not help you, try to provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

This adds some details to the helpful answer by @TheIceBear.

As he indicates, one way to get a Stata daily date from your run-together date variable is convert it to a string first. But `tostring` is just one way to do that and not essential. (I have nothing against `tostring`, as its original author, but it is better suited to other tasks.)

Here I use `daily()` not `date()`: the results are identical, but it's a good idea to use `daily()`: `date()` is all too often misunderstood as a generic date function, whereas all it does is produce daily dates (or missings).

To get a numeric year variable, just divide by 10000 and round down. You could convert to a string, extract the first 4 characters, and then convert to numeric, but that's more operations.

```
clear 
set obs 1 
gen long date = 20111017
format date %8.0f 

gen ddate = daily(strofreal(date, "%8.0f"), "YMD")
format %td ddate 
gen year = floor(date/10000)

list  

     +-----------------------------+
     |     date       ddate   year |
     |-----------------------------|
  1. | 20111017   17oct2011   2011 |
     +-----------------------------+
```